# Python: find strings inside dynamic text and put another text in front of the line

Tags: python, regex, replace, find, findall

I've tried to find / build a solution but it's too complicated for me at the moment. I have a text from SAP GUI for Scripting (stored in tkinter's scrooledtext).

```
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 4
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[17]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsG_SELONETABSTRIP/tabpTAB001/ssubSUBSCR_PRESEL:SAPLSDH4:0220/sub:SAPLSDH4:0220/ctxtG_SELFLD_TAB-LOW[3,24]").setFocus
session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/lbl[1,1]").setFocus
session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 33
```

I would like to find every line when .sendVKey occurs, and put newtext at start of the line (or above the line) - eg in example there are 3 lines:

Added new text before sendkey text occurs!

```
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 4
```

(...)
Added new text before sendkey text occurs!<\b>

```
session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 0
```

(...)

Tried using re.sub, re.findall and replace, but I think this is not a good approach. My working code is below, but it is not dynamic (in .sendVkey method it can be different window (0, 1, 2, 3 etc) in ("wnd[1]"). Any hints / solutions? Please help :(

```
    def multiple_replace(string, rep_dict):
        pattern = re.compile("|".join([re.escape(k) for k in sorted(rep_dict, key=len, reverse=True)]), flags=re.DOTALL)
        return pattern.sub(lambda x: rep_dict[x.group(0)], string)


    date_div = RPAcode.get("1.0", tk.END)
    delay_vba_function = "   Added new text before sendkey text occurs"
"
    replaced_text = multiple_replace(date_div, {'.sendVKey' : '\n' + delay_vba_function + '\n' + '.sendVKey', \
                                                'session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey' : '\n' + delay_vba_function + '\n' + 'session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey', \
                                                'session.findById("wnd[2]").sendVKey' : '\n' + delay_vba_function + '\n' + 'session.findById("wnd[2]").sendVKey', \
                                                'session.findById("wnd[3]").sendVKey' : '\n' + delay_vba_function + '\n' + 'session.findById("wnd[3]").sendVKey'})
    #print(replaced_text)

    RPAcode.delete('0.0', tk.END) #Deletes previous data
    RPAcode.insert(1.0, replaced_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to check whether a substring is in a string is by using the `in`-operator (in Python3.5 at least). Consider the following:

```
text = 'session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 4'
if '.sendVKey' in text:
    text = '(...)' + text
text
```

If you run it in the terminal, the output is gonna be:

```
'(...)session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 4'
```

So, as you can see, the script even adds already some text in front of the text line. If you don't say `text = '(...)' + text`, but `text = '(...)\n' + text`, the `(...)` would show up in a line above the actual text. If you put the above code sample into a for loop iterating through all text lines, I think that approach might solve your problem.

**Edit:**

You first have to split the text into lines before iterating through the lines. I guess that is precisely what you need:

```
text = """session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 4
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[17]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsG_SELONETABSTRIP/tabpTAB001/ssubSUBSCR_PRESEL:SAPLSDH4:0220
session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/lbl[1,1]").setFocus
session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 33"""

query_text = ".sendVKey"
addition = "(...) "

def indicate_lines(text, query_text, indication):
    result = ''
    text = text.splitlines()
    for line in text:
        if query_text in line:
            result = result + indication + line + "\n"
        else:
            result = result + line + "\n"
    return result

result = indicate_lines(text, query_text, addition)
print(result)
```

The result is gonna be:

```
(...) session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 4
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[17]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsG_SELONETABSTRIP/tabpTAB001
/ssubSUBSCR_PRESEL:SAPLSDH4:0220
(...) session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/lbl[1,1]").setFocus
(...) session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 33
```

Note that I would expect regex to perform faster in case you want to have a scalable solution (because `for`-loops are comparatively slow in Python). But for most medium sized applications that will do the job.

Comment: Thanx Daniel B this works partially. I've used the method you mention: 
`code`
    delay_vba_function = "   Call vbaDELAYTIME \n"
    text = RPAcode.get("1.0", tk.END)
    if '.sendVKey' in text:
        text = delay_vba_function + text

    RPAcode.delete('0.0', tk.END) #Deletes previous data
    RPAcode.insert(1.0, text)
`code`
but unfortunately Python change just the first occurence (i have 3 sendVKey occurences). Result should change session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 0 and session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 33 also...

Comment: Your solution with a loop works perfectly :) Thank you very much :) I thought I had to use some loops but I didn't know how to do it (I programmed a lot in VBA but these 2 are different languages with many similarities)

Comment: You're welcome! And please don't forget to mark the question as answered. 
My efficiency concern primarily concerned applications where you want to work on gigabytes (or more) of text. But as long as that isn't the case, for-loops are indeed the most convenient and handy solution to go for.